# Build Notification received from Firebase in Library Project

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-pendingintent, android-push-notification

I have `Firebase` implemented at application level to receive push messages. In the library project, I have a `BroadcastReceiver` to intercept push messages. I want to build notification from the library and not from the application.
Incase of app in foreground state, when I create a Pending intent, the **MainActivity** context **available at the app level** is passed in the pending intent, upon which if the notification is tapped, I am redirected to **MainActivity**. Now if the app is in killed state and push message is received, my broadcast receiver in the library intercepts the incoming message, but not able to create notification because the MainActivity context is null as the **MainActivity** at app level is not available in the stack trace. Can anyone assist how to achieve this?

Below is my code :

```
val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext,activityContext::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
mIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

where, **activityContext** in the `Intent` is the context of **MainActivity** received inside the library project from app level.

When app is in **foreground state**, **activityContext** is available and notification gets generated. But when app is in **killed state**, **activityContext** remains null leading to failure in building the notification.

Comment: Doesn't Firebase automatically generate and display notification when your application is not in foreground?

Comment: @Dhaval Firebase only triggers push messages to Android devices. Its dependent on whether the notification is of message type or data type. For message type, Android OS handles itself in notification tray and generates them but with this we cannot extract the data payload sent along. With data type notification, we can get the payload but have to create our notifications ourselves. Since we are following later approach, so stuck with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Activity`'s `Context`, because if the app isn't running, it doesn't exist.

You should have the app pass the library the **name** of the `MainActivity` (ie: fully qualified class name). The library can then use the **name** of the `MainActivity` to set the component parameters in the `Intent`.

This means instead of this:

```
val mIntent = Intent(applicationContext,activityContext::class.java)
```

You want to do something like this (my Kotlin syntax may be wrong, sorry):

```
val mIntent = Intent()
mIntent.setClassName(applicationContext, nameOfMainActivity)
```

Comment: I see. It looks like you need a hook, so that the library code can call a method that is provided by the application, which will return the name of the `MainActivity`. Your `BroadcastReceiver` would then call that method in `onReceive()` to determine the name of the `MainActivity`. Another way to do this would be to add some "meta-data" to the manifest, that your `BroadcastReceiver` could read to determine the name of the `MainActivity`. Alternatively you could store the name of the `MainActivity` in `SharedPreferences`